# Display pdf file with proper indentation

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, web-deployment

I want to Display Pdf file on webpage. The Pdf File contains Python Program which has indentation. But while displaying the file i am not able to get the proper spacing as in the pdf.

```
import PyPDF2
def read_file(request):
    pdfFileObj = open('media/documents/from_django.pdf', 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
    text=pageObj.extractText()
    pdfFileObj.close()
    context = {'file_content': text}
    return render(request, "file.html", context)



HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>File</title>
</head>
<body>
{{ file_content}}
</body>
</html>
```